# Count number of duplicate values in a list<string> and store in dictionary

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of string, in this list there are some strings which are duplicated twice or more.

I want to count them and add them to dictionary like this:

```
List<string> lst = { 'A' , 'B' , 'B' , 'c' , 'c' , 'c' };
```

and it goes to dictionary like this :

```
A , 1
B , 2
c , 3
```

How can I do this ?!

Answer (score 3):

```
var dict = lst.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

If you want to do it in a case insensitive way

```
var dict = lst.GroupBy(x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase )
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: Fast and Simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
  List<Char> lst = new {  // Note "Char"
    'A' , 'B' , 'B' , 'c' , 'c' , 'c' };

  var dictionary = list
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key,
                  chunk => chunk.Count());
```